# Why does CHKDSK run everytime I boot my Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

Every time I boot my Windows 7 machine, CHKDSK runs.

I have a feeling that the operating system is trying to tell me something, but I don't understand what it is. Any ideas?

Everything works fine so long as I don't reboot.

I treat my computer well, never shutdown with going through Windows "shutdown", etc.

Comment: Your last sentence is a bit ambiguous...if you aren't using Windows shutdown, how do you power off your PC? This could be part of the problem...

Comment: Possibly related to your issue is certain software software have caused Windows7 CHKDSK to run too often.  Antivir had issues recently - http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/security/353734/windows-7-chkdsk-bug-linked-to-antivirus-software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to stop chkdsk from running on startup is to use `chkntfs`:

```
chkntfs /x c:
```

Where `c:` is the drive you're excluding from the disk check. You can use multiple drives as arguments like so:

```
chkntfs /x c: d:
```

Explanation of the various switches:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>chkntfs /?
Displays or modifies the checking of disk at boot time.

CHKNTFS volume [...]
CHKNTFS /D
CHKNTFS /T[:time]
CHKNTFS /X volume [...]
CHKNTFS /C volume [...]

  volume         Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                 mount point, or volume name.
  /D             Restores the machine to the default behavior; all drives are
                 checked at boot time and chkdsk is run on those that are
                 dirty.
  /T:time        Changes the AUTOCHK initiation countdown time to the
                 specified amount of time in seconds.  If time is not
                 specified, displays the current setting.
  /X             Excludes a drive from the default boot-time check.  Excluded
                 drives are not accumulated between command invocations.
  /C             Schedules a drive to be checked at boot time; chkdsk will run
                 if the drive is dirty.

If no switches are specified, CHKNTFS will display if the specified drive is
dirty or scheduled to be checked on next reboot.
```

Comment: No explanation for the neg, figures.

Comment: Sorry, that was me - a while ago.  

Your suggestion is masking the problem, not solving it.  It's like telling someone to turn off the logging of a specific error message instead of dealing with why the message is showing.

Also, if you only had a couple upvotes I wouldn't have done it, but I just couldn't handle that many people supporting the idea of ignoring the problem as a fix.

Comment: Do not forget to run the cmd window as "Run as administrator", otherwise it won't work. Tried it myself, worked like a charm..

Comment: Thanks for this answer, John. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I know it's been eons, but that comment just sounds spiteful and parochial. Let me assure you there are legit reasons to want to do this, such as Windows paranoia where I'm switching between installations on different HDDs on the same machine and suddenly Windows wants to check all of them everytime I load that OS after using another one. It never finds anything wrong, of course, it just doesn't like not being the sole OS in control... Rather than endure nonsensical disk checks, I'll run them manually when really needed, thanks very much.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter "spiteful and parochial", sorry you took it that way..  John T and I have both been here a long time, I'm sure he didn't take my comment that way.  And while I'm also sorry if that seems parochial to you, but that's my opinion based on years of experience.  To your specific scenario: If you're dual booting, and it's causing the drive to be flagged dirty, then _something is wrong_, as every OS should close it's file system connections cleanly on shutdown.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Agreed, they _should_ shut down cleanly, but don't. In my case, I can reproduce the problem at will by shutting down Win10 on one drive normally. If I were to start up the same OS the next time, it'd be happy, but if I start up Win7 on another drive, it wants to check all my HDDs. Same vice versa. Not disputing your experience that these checks are mostly correct, but I dare say the likelihood of three drives all developing a mysterious problem _at the same time_ is far lower than the likelihood of both OSs setting a dirty flag erroneously, leading me to want John T's workaround.

Comment: Lots of people dual boot between Windows 7 and 10 without the problem you're describing.  Your system has a problem someplace, and since you've gone thru 3 drives, its probably not the drives. ;)  Anyhow, if you are willing to accept that you are just ignoring/masking something, and are willing to accept any risks, then good on ya.  But it doesn't change why I said what I said.

Answer (score 6):

If Windows is running `CHKDSK` at every boot then you have a problem.

Using `CHKNTFS` to exclude the drives from checks at boot is not a good idea at all, that's just ignoring the problem.

If you are ensuring you always shutdown properly, and it appears to do so, then something is causing the dirty bit to be flagged before power off.

This can be caused by many things (hardware or software), and it's impossible to pinpoint based on what we know.  But it's most likely a hardware issue (based on too many years of experience).  If you have warranty, save your data and get them to fix it, should be EASY for them if it's happening every time (and they should have all the spare parts available).

If you want to try and diagnose it yourself, then please go try a few things and come back with specific questions.

**Hint**: try Windows power adjustments, and HDD manufacturer diagnostics to start)

Comment: I agree that preventing CHKDSK from running is indeed just ignoring the problem.  I don't know how the answer got chosen as I am sure the OP asked *why* it was running and now how to turn it off.  I wish you gave more specifics in your answer, though, especially with "please go try a few things".  I am having this problem now and would like to know some things to try.

Answer (score 1):

John T beat me to the command, but in addition, it is worth noting that this is controlled through "Boot Execute" in [Microsoft/Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), you can delete entries there, or go to the registry key they are stored in:

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CURRENTCONTROLSET\CONTROL\Session Manager`

Autochk.exe seems to be there by default - it is just the c: (and any additional drive) parts that you need to delete. The default value for the registry key (incase you delete something by accident) is `autocheck autochk *`.