# How to disable CHKDSK permanently, windows 10/11

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to completely and permanently disable CHKDSK on windows 10 and 11, reason is a long story but as a summary: I work with complex custom builds having multiple SOs(mostly Linux) and 2 NTFSs partitions dedicated to files, some years ago Windows 7 deleted my 2 partitions dedicated to files(I know it because the partitions were empty and just hidden CHKDSK logs were found), I bought a file recovery software and recovered some of my files(not all, and some of them recovered to a huge common folder instead of original directories), I found a blog that said CHKDSK deletes the disk if there are corrupted files or disk damage and found how to disable it(supposedly), performed it and 2 years later, Windows again deleted my partitions, but this time recovery worked worst and lost many files(many others still un a big bag of recovered but unorganized files).

Now I have a new build with windows 10(will upgrade to 11 soon) but I am scared about CHKDSK again, so I want to completely disable CHKDSK (and any other windows background process that could cause the partition to be deleted), what's the most effective way of doing it?

Comment: Windows 7 does not delete partitions. Chkdsk does not delete drives. Can there be unwanted effects from running chkdsk like deleted files, sure. But there's no code inside chkdsk that tells it to actively go delete drives. What you should consider is, if it's a wise idea to let multiple OSs be master of NTFS formatted drives.

Answer (score -1):

Read this former Superuser thread for information,

Also, disabling something that tells you that you have a problem or a failing disk does not seem sensible.

---

Why does CHKDSK run everytime I boot my Windows 7 machine?

[Why does CHKDSK run everytime I boot my Windows 7 machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/89648/why-does-chkdsk-run-everytime-i-boot-my-windows-7-machine)

---

Recovering files that CHKDSK deletes:

So, you can go to the root directory of your drive to see if there is a found.000 folder which is hidden by default when find files get lost after CHKDSK.

Firstly, you should view hidden folders in Windows 10.

```
Open File Explorer.

Select View in menu bar.

Navigate to Options.

Select Change folder and search options from the submenu.

Shift to View tab.

Check Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

Click on the OK button to confirm changes.
```

Then:

7 Ways To Recover CHK Files Created by CHKDSK and SCANDISK

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-recover-chk-files-created-by-chkdsk-and-scandisk/

---